# How to debug ASP.NET Core webapp using a URL other than localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have a web application that behaves differently depending on the hostname.  To test it on my local PC, I will then need to arrange for IISExpress to run the web application using a specific name that I provide in Project -> Properties -> Debug, such as **http://mywebsite:58981/**.

[image]

But when start debugging, a pop up message "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'" pops up.  And Windows 10 activity center alerted me of a message and upon clicking it, I received this pop-up from IIS Express:

[image]

I tried what other users suggested such as deleting the .vs folder containing the applicationhost.config and restarted the solution, but it still doesn't work.  I even made sure that IIS Express doesn't have anything else running:

[image]

But if I changed the App URL back to **http://localhost:58981/**, deleted the **.vs** folder, and open the solution, I can debug as usual.

So my question is: how do I change the URL from **localhost** to something else?  I'm running Visual Studio 2019 and my Windows 10 is 1903 edition.

Comment: Publish the web app to IIS and then you can test it out or debug on IIS. Microsoft designs VS/IIS Express integration to work only for localhost for a reason, which you probably should not challenge. Of course, there can be third party options. More background can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/what-should-you-check-when-visual-studio-cannot-debug-asp-net-core-projects-4b5db8c5e129

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first advise is **run Visual Studio as Administrator.**

Modify the IIS Express configuration files , go to edit file :

`\{project folder}\.vs\{yourWebApplicationName}\config\applicationhost.config`

You will find something like this(find with your application name):

```
<site name="WebApplication3" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="WebApplication3 AppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53717:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44325:localhost" />

    </bindings>
</site>
```

Add in `<bindings>`, add another row with your own IP, port number:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53717:mywebsite" />
```

Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` edit the `hosts` file (copy to another place ,edit and copy back):

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       mywebsite
#   ::1             localhost
```

Then you could use `http://mywebsite:53707` to debug your application , you may comment out `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in `Configure` to handle HTTP request .

Comment: Thanks!  Running as administrator does the trick.  And manually adding additional binding solution is elegant and I just need to do it once, so once it's done, I can switch between hostname without restarting the debugging session.

Comment: running vs as admin is OK? i remember reading somewhere that running vs as admin can cause some trouble but i don't remember what was the trouble tbh.